# Invalid syntax when using PyMySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I'm learning using Python with MySQL. The same query works differently between Mysql and PyMySQL. For example: In MySQL console I have a table named "pages"

```
INSERT INTO pages (title,content) VALUES ("test title","test content")
```

And this works. In Python, I import PyMySQL, I create a connection and then type `cursor = "cur"`. When I run:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO pages (title,content) VALUES ("test title","test content")")
```

.. it raises an error : invalid syntax. But when I try this with the place holder:

```
cur.execute("insert into pages (title,content) values (%s,%s)",("test title","test content"))
```

Then it works! So I was confused why same query work in MySQL but not in python,and does It means I should always use place holder when using PyMySQL?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you should use parameterized queries.  However, if you look at the statement that doesn't work, think about how you are using the double quotes.  You are basically closing your string -- use single quotes instead there and it would work too...

Comment: Yeah,I see,such a rookie mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the last version (the *parameterized* query) should be the most preferred one since you don't need to put the quotes around the placeholders at all letting the database driver figure out the type conversion and the quotes automatically. And, this way you are safe from [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Now, to answering your question. 
If you want to use double quotes inside double quotes, you need to *escape* them:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO pages (title,content) VALUES (\"test title\", \"test content\")")
```

Or, use single quotes outside and double quotes inside:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO pages (title,content) VALUES ("test title", "test content")')
```

Comment: +1 For SQL Injection response. Check out [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/python.html) for how to prevent SQL Injection in python, as SQL injection is a nightmare.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

In python you cannot concatenate strings by doing this

```
a = "foo"
b = "bar"
"Foo bar" a " baz " b
```

which is what you were trying to do. Instead you must do `"Foo bar" + a + " baz " + b`. However, if you use `%s`, you are using formatting (based on C's `printf` function) and you can use commas to format a string in this manner

```
a = "foo"
b = "bar"
"Foo bar %s baz %s" % (a, b)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ,I see my problem is.